# How do I listen to changes in Dependency properties from within an attached dependency property?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, dependency-properties

In WPF/SL, I could use the [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx) to add listeners on value changes.

In Win8, this class does not seem to exist and so I am looking for an alternate (hopefully as easy) way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `PropertyChangeNotifier` class as described in this [blog post](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/)

After you create it you can use it on attached properties like this:

```
ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
...
PropertyChangeNotifier notifier = new PropertyChangeNotifier(listBox, “(Grid).Row”);
notifier.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnValueChanged);
```

Also, DependencyPropertyDescriptor doesn't exists in .net 4.5 client profile. However, it does exist in the normal profile. So if you must have it just change the target framework of your project.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Using an own AttachedProperty seems that it is not working. Do we have to specify somehow the namespace? We have tried passing directly the DependencyProperty without any improvement. The change event is never thrown.